# Override Javascript function using Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm using a library that has a class defined like this:

```
RoundDown = function () {
    this.prop = 5.5
    this.do_something = function() {
        return "base class: " + this.prop
    };
};
```

Using CoffeeScript, I want to extend do_something so it will run its original function plus new code. Subclassing it seems like a clean solution, but the base class' function gets called, rather than the overridden function.

```
# Subclass overriding round function
class RoundUp extends RoundDown
    do_something: () ->
        return super() + " Subclass code"
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Wehrdo/ta5r5c3a/8/).

What is the correct way to do? Thanks!

Comment: The first example is technically not a "class" as Coffee understands. You need to add the methods on the prototype, that's what `extends` knows about. Now you are adding the method as an own property.

Comment: @elclanrs It's also not a "class" as most JavaScript developers understand :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that RoundDown is setting a field of the instance, not of the prototype. The ideal way to fix this would be

```
RoundDown = function () {
    this.prop = 5.5
};
RoundDown.prototype.do_something = function() {
    return "base class: " + this.prop
};
```

But maybe you don't have permission to modify RoundDown, eg it is in a library, so do this

```
class RoundUp extends RoundDown
  constructor: ->
    super()
    oldDoSomething = @do_something 
    @do_something = ->
      oldDoSomething.call(this) + " Subclass code"
```

Comment: Correct, I don't have permission to modify the library. (Well, I technically do, but for maintainability, I don't want to) This seems close, but the subclass doesn't have access to the base class's properties.

Comment: Just for clarification, if you place the code in the jsFiddle, you'll see that it prints "base class: undefined Subclass code". When the base class tries to access "this.prop" it gets returned as undefined.

Comment: @Wehrdo fixed; was missing Function::call, so `this` was wrong

Comment: Excellent! It works great in my actual code. Thanks for your help! I'm gradually getting more used to Javascript's prototypal inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Using js2coffee converter: [js2.coffee](http://js2.coffee):

```
RoundDown = ->
  @prop = 5.5

  @do_something = ->
    'base class: ' + @prop
```